# In Spring data solr 3.0.6 release , choose solr core dynamically

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data-jpa, solrj, spring-data-solr

I am using spring data solr 3.0.6, and standalone solr server 7.0.0 and I have multiple solr cores in my solr server, and I want to choose one of them dynamically , Here is the configuration I Have

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = "com.solr.repository")
public class SolrConfiguration
{


 @Bean
  public SolrOperations solrTemplate(SolrClient solr) {
    return new SolrTemplate(solr);
  }



  @Bean(name = "solrClient")
  public SolrClient createSolrClient()
  {
     HttpSolrClient.Builder builder = new HttpSolrClient.Builder().withBaseSolrUrl(solrInstanceUrl);
    return builder.build();
}
```

}

SolrRepository

```
public interface SolrRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<SolrDocument, Integer>
{
 @Query("name:*?0* OR content:*?0*")
 @Highlight()
  public HighlightPage<SolrDocument> findByQueryAnnotation(String searchTerm, Pageable pageable);
}
```

SolrDocument (domain class for Solr repository)

```
@SolrDocument
public class SolrDocument
{
}
```

ServicePojo (service class)

```
 public class ServicePojo
    {
        @Autowired
        SolrRepository solrRepository;

        public void findData(int id)
        {
           solrRepository.findById(id);
         }
    }
```

Now I want to use methods of repository interface like `findById()` etc, but as I mentioned above, I have different cores, and I want to point a specific core to perform searching, before calling method solrRepository.findById() I need to mention which core it should point. So where we can tell to solr server , which Core to be used ?

If I use annotation `@SolrDocument(collectionName="core1")`, then it works fine and it points to "core1", but I want this to be dynamic. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using Repository (`SolrRepository`). But you can do this using `SolrTemplate`.

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/solr/core/SolrTemplate.html) is the link to the 3.0.6 `SolrTemplate` API. If you look at some of the methods like query or getById, it takes an argument collectionName. You can pass coreName here.

Comment: I was doing this stuff in previous version of spring-data-solr (3.0.0.M1) with
MulticoreSolrClientFactory, but in the latest version 3.0.6, it doesnt seems possible. 



if you say its possible in Solrtemplate then please let me know how ?

Comment: the reason i wanted to use solrRepository is because I need to use custom queries (I have updated my above solrRepository class). so if solrTemplate registers collectionName in it  or in solrClient, then I can generate solrRepository from SolrRepositoryFactory. But using direct solrTemplate will not not help me


SolrRepositoryFactory solrRepositoryFactory = new SolrRepositoryFactory(solrTemplate);

 solrRepository = solrRepositoryFactory.getRepository(SolrRepository.class);

Comment: Not sure if i understood your point. You can keep your repository class. But you can create a custom repository (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) where you Autowire SolrTemplate and write your custom queries.

Comment: above SolrRepository itself is a custom repository. Query features like "highlights" are being provided by "data.solr.repository" API, so I have to use repositories interfaces  to use my custom queries, if i autowire solrTemplate then I can use only methods which are provided by solrTemplate , I wont be able  to use other features of reposiories interface which i can get by writing my own queries (just have look a query above in SolrRepository class)

Comment: Everything which can be done by SolrRepository can be done using SolrTemplate. May be u need to write a bit more code.

Comment: yes, but it become very difficult and combersome, if i need to search something by request paramater then solrTemplate is not that easy to manage, So I was looking for core to be registsred by solrTemplate or solrClient. It seems to be possible with  solrTemplate.setSolrConverter()  may be , but I am not sure ,,

Comment: Ya. But there is no other way. If you wish to change core name dynamically, u cannot use repository class. It is same for CRUDRepository, MongoRepository, .....etc